# TryParseExact always shows false

Tags: c#

I am trying to validate the date which is saved in string (20170123) but i am always getting false. can you please help me to get the True output. Not getting any error when i execute it.

Sample given below:

```
bool testing =  DateTime.TryParseExact("20170123", "yyyy-MM-DD", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dateValue);
           Console.WriteLine(testing);
```

Comment: There are hyphens in `yyyy-MM-DD`. There are no hyphens in `20170123`.

Comment: DD must be in lower case

Comment: Of course you're not getting any error. You only get errors with `ParseExact`. The `Try` version of the method is specifically _meant_ to not throw exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Replace `format` to value without hyphens and `day` part of `format` should be in lower case `dd`.

```
bool testing = DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "20170123", 
    "yyyyMMdd", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
    out dateValue);
```

Comment: it works..thanks you !